# Error: “The network name cannot be found” during In-place upgrade from CRM 2015 to CRM 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm

During the "In-place upgrade" procedure from CRM 2015 to CRM 2016 (on premise) the following error message popped up:

[image: error]

```
Error| System.Exception: Action Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.InstallSqlClrHelperAction failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: The network name cannot be found.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.Helpers.CopyDatabaseFile(String sourcePath, String sourceFileName, Boolean isBuildEnvironment, String 

sqlServerName, String destinationFilePath, String destinationFileName, String& copyDestinationPath)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.InstallSqlClrHelperAction.Do(IDictionary parameters)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Shared.CrmAction.ExecuteAction(CrmAction action, IDictionary parameters, Boolean undo)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---, Error, AbortRetryIgnore, Option1
```

Any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Comment: Check the logs to determine which network name could not be identified.